# What is the difference between -webkit-transform:perspective and -webkit-perspective

Tags: html, css

What is the difference between `-webkit-transform: perspective` and `-webkit-perspective` (given on -webkit- as the vendor.)

I tried this in the same case, but they return different result. Anyone know if it actually gives any difference?

Comment: "I tried this in the same case, but they return different result. Anyone know if it actually gives any difference?" What do you think?

Comment: At least, you could tell us more what your different results are. To get more insight what may be happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a pretty clear explanation:

> The -webkit-perspective property applies the same transform as the perspective() transform function, except that it applies only to the children of the element, not to the transform on the element itself.

Source: [CSS property: `-webkit-perspective`](http://css-infos.net/property/-webkit-perspective)